# I uninstalled zypper in openSuse Tumbleweed by accident, how do I get it back?

Tags: rpm, opensuse, zypper

I thought I'd do some cleaning up, so I ran:

```bash
zypper packages --orphaned | awk -F'|' 'NR==0 || NR==1 || NR==2 || NR==3 || NR==4 {next} {print $3}' \
    | grep -v Name | sudo xargs zypper remove --clean-deps
```

And somehow `zypper` itself was one of the packages that got removed. So now `zypper` is missing, how do I go about getting it back?

Comment: If zypper was uninstalled but not its dependencies I think you can download the [this zypper rpm package](https://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/opensuse/tumbleweed/repo/oss/x86_64/zypper-1.14.61-1.1.x86_64.rpm) or download and specific package  from [here](https://pkgs.org/download/zypper)

Comment: To install it use: `rpm --install zypper-file.rpm`. Btw, I'm not really sure if by using this method (using `rpm`) will automatically update the `zypper` program for future releases

Answer (score 0):

These are the `zypper` package dependencies:

```
start cmd:> rpm -q --requires zypper
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
/bin/sh
config(zypper) = 1.14.60-1.3
libaugeas.so.0()(64bit)
libaugeas.so.0(AUGEAS_0.1.0)(64bit)
libaugeas.so.0(AUGEAS_0.8.0)(64bit)
libaugeas0 >= 1.10.0
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.32)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit)
libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.3.1)(64bit)
libreadline.so.8()(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6()(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.5)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.14)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.18)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.26)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.29)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.32)(64bit)
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit)
libxml2.so.2()(64bit)
libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.4.30)(64bit)
libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.5.0)(64bit)
libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.0)(64bit)
libzypp >= 17.31.13
libzypp.so.1722()(64bit)
libzypp.so.1722(ZYPP_plain)(64bit)
procps
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1
```

I don't know how much you have deleted. If it was just the `zypper` package (or a file from it) then re-installing this package would be enough. Otherwise you will be told by the error message when you try to install the downloades package(s) with

```
rpm -i $package_name ...
```

You can download the package(s) here:

https://software.opensuse.org/search?baseproject=openSUSE%3AFactory&q=zypper

Comment: It seems most things zypper depended on was also removed, ugh, manually downloading it all and installing it will be a pain, maybe it's better I re-install linux altogether...